# Copy certain excel columns based on ones criteria

Tags: excel, vba, button, range, criteria

First thing I did was create a button that would copy certain cells using this code:

> Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A,B:B,D:D").Copy _ 
>   and it worked fine.

Second, I found the code that would copy all details in a row based on the criteria of one, in this case if there was an "A" in the "Location" column.

> Private Sub ENTIREROW_Click()
>   'Sub copyrows()
>
> Dim i As Range, Cell As Object
>
> Set i = Range("D:D") 'Substitute with the range which includes your True/False values
>
> For Each Cell In i
>
> ```
>    If IsEmpty(Cell) Then
>        Exit Sub
>    End If
>
>    If Cell.Value = "A" Then
>        Cell.ENTIREROW.Copy
>        Sheet2.Select 'Substitute with your sheet
>        ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Select
>        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
>        ActiveSheet.Paste
>    End If
> ```
>
> Next
>
> End Sub

[image: Spreadsheet data]

My question is, how do I copy all information in the specified columns (A,B,D) where there is an "A" in "Location" in one button.

Furthermore, this is my example data, the sheet I will actually use this on has 34 columns to copy. Is there a more efficient way of setting a range when you don't want an entire sequence, everything but the data in column C?

Thanks in advance and apologies for my explanation skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way maybe to:

- filter your source
- hide column C
- copy the result using `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` into the destination
- Unhide column C on the source sheet
- remove the autofilter

Using `xlPasteValues` only pastes the visible cells from the source - so no column C

The code then looks like this:    .

```
Sub CopyRows()
    With Sheets(1).Range([A2], [A2].SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
        [A1].AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="A"
        [C:C].EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        .Copy
        [C:C].EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End With
    With Sheets(2)
        If .Cells(Sheets(2).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) = "" Then 'it's a clean sheet
            .Cells(Sheets(2).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Else
            .Cells(Sheets(2).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheet1.[A1].AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey that worked perfectly. For my actual sheet I need these columns shown: "A:K, M:Z, AA:AB, AD:AJ". Is it better to hide all other columns or is there a way to only select that given range?

Comment: @drblacko On `Sheet1` press `Ctrl + End` to go to the last cell. If that last cell is in the last column that has something in, then there is no need to hide any further columns. If the last cell is in a blank column, then delete all columns between that and you last significant column and save the workbook to reset the used range.

Comment: Waaaay late, but for posterity .... I'd suggest creating a "Slicer" range: `With Sheets(1): Set SliceRange = Union(.Columns(1).Resize(, 11),.Columns(13).Resize(, 14), ... etc.): End With` and then use `Intersect(SlicerRange, {your visible rows range here}).Copy`.